# Accurate file-tree for a virtual windows(and linux) system? | Hacking Simulator Game

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, directory-listing

I am creating a hacking Simulator in Python where the user has to break into PCs(totally unexpected, right?)

I need a minimal file-tree for my virtual Windows(And also Linux) PC.(The tree will only represent an OS in the game) I have tried figuring this out myself but I just don't know what folders are important or even standard.

I don't need anything elaborate just a few folders with a brief discription of what should be in them (besides the obvious ones like Documents/Downloads/Pictures) but i do want the file-tree to look legitimate.

Bonus points for file ideas to go in them.

Edit: I just need to know what would be a good minimal file-tree that would well represent either a Windows or Linux system for my game. Like what folders from said OS are iconically important.

P.S: I was told in GameDev to ask here.

Comment: I actually did give you a suggestion to use a VM and use its file system has a model for your simulator.  I won't submit an answer because I feel I would do you a disservice if I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linux**

In general, I suggest to look at [The Linux Directory Structure, Explained](https://www.howtogeek.com/117435/htg-explains-the-linux-directory-structure-explained/) from HowToGeek, it provides easy to understand descriptions of the basic folder structure for Linux.

Note: there may be discrepancies from distro to distro.

I also suggest to run [jslinux](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) which has a minimalistic Linux implementation running on JavaScript directly on the browser.

You may also get a live CD from a Linux distro and use that for reference. Since your game is oriented to hacking, you may want to consider distros dedicated to penetration testing or computer forensics.

---

These are the root folders from jslinux: `/bin`, `/dev`, `/etc`, `/home`, `/lib`, `/lost+found`, `/mnt`, `/opt`, `/proc`, `/root`, `/sbin`, `/sys`, `/usr`, `/var`.

The "iconic" set for Linux would be `bin`, `etc`, `usr`, `home`, `var`, and `dev`.

I'll not go into the detail of each folder, yet I want to talk about a few of them. First `/dev`, where you will find the devices files. These are files that represent the storage devices (e.g. `/dev/hda` is IDE device, `dev/hda1` will be the first partition of the first IDE device, etc...). It is expected to find a few pseudo devices:

- `/dev/null`: that when writing to it, accepts anything and discard it. When reading it it always at the end of the file.
- `/dev/zero`: also discards everything. When reading it, it produces an endless stream of NUL (character 0).
- `dev/full`: also produces an endless stream of NUL, but if you try to write it will yield a "disk full" error.
- `dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`: When you read from these, they produce and endless stream pseudo-random values. It is possible to write to `dev/random`, this will add entropy to the pseudo-random generator. There could be vulnerabilities to be exploited by flooding `dev/random` in such way that it affects a software that uses it for cryptography. See [Analysis of the Linux Random Number Generator](http://www.pinkas.net/PAPERS/gpr06.pdf)

I also want to mention `/bin`, which is where you will find the basic executables of the operating system. You may also find `/sbin` which tools that require elevated privileges to run. And then there is `/usr/bin` that has programs installed by the user or non-essential packaged added by the operating system.

Speaking of user data, you will find the equivalent of user folders under `\home`. In particular, I want to mention that the "recycle bin" is responsibility of the desktop environment (and as you may know, there are multiple for Linux) but it will usually be somewhere within the user folder.

Another relevant folder is `/var`, which will have activity logs among other things, which you may want to have the player edit to remove traces of the hacking activities (note: if the intruder just deletes the logs there will be a chance to recover them with forensic tools).

And then the famous `/etc` which will have configuration files, including `/etc/passwd` with the hashes of the passwords of the users... which the play might want to crack with some software for the task. You will also find     `/etc/hosts` which has the local mapping for hosts names to IPs.

Note: If you want to make a realistic simulation of the file system, don't forget the Permissions.

---

**Windows**

These changes from version to version, although any modern version (post Vista) of windows will have the [Known Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx). Something like this (based on Windows 10):

```
C:\
   Windows\
           Fonts\
           Resources\
           System32\
   ProgramFiles\
                CommonFiles\
                Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\
   ProgramData\
               Microsoft\Windows\
                                 Ringtones\
                                 GameExplorer\
                                 DeviceMetadataStore\
                                 Templates\
                                 Start Menu\
                                            Programs\
                                                     Administrative Tools\
                                                     StartUp\
               OEM Links\
   Users\
         Public\
                Desktop\
                Documents\
                Downloads\
                Music\
                      SampleMusic\
                      SamplePlaylists\
                Pictures\
                         SamplePictures\
                AccountPictures\
                Videos\
                       SampleVideos\
         TheUser\
                 Desktop\
                 Documents\
                 Downloads\
                 Favorites\
                 Music\
                       Playlists\
                 Pictures\
                 Videos\
                 OneDrive\
                          Documents\
                          Pictures\
                                   CameraRoll
                 AppData\
                         LocalLow\
                         Local\
                               Programs\
                                        Common\
                               Microsoft\
                                         Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\
                                         Windows\
                                                 Burn\Burn\
                                                 Ringtones\
                                                 GameExplorer\
                                                 History\
                                                 RoamingTiles\
                         Roaming\Microsoft\
                                           Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\
                                                                          User Pinned\
                                                                                      ImplicitAppShortcuts\
                                           Windows\
                                                   Templates\
                                                   SendTo\
                                                   Recent\
                                                   Network Shortcuts\
                                                   Printer Shortcuts\
                                                   Libraries\
                                                             Documents.library-ms
                                                             Music.library-ms
                                                             Pictures.library-ms
                                                             Videos.library-ms
                                                   AccountPictures\
                                                   Start Menu\
                                                              Programs\
                                                                       Administrative Tools\
                                                                       StartUp\
                                                   Application Shortcuts\
```

*Note: Of course "TheUser" is the user name*

You can see there is a lot of stuff, which is why I'm not providing description of each one, yet you can find them in the link I provided above.

So, you have "Program Files", "ProgramData" (usually hidden), "Windows", and "Users". Also hidden you may find a ["Recovery"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/what-is-the-crecovery-folder/a2067cd8-7de2-4871-98a6-2b882050a892) folder, and don't forget the [Recycle Bin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash_(computing)).

In fact, what I listed above isn't everything windows installs, you may get a [Windows Virtual Machine from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) which is a test copy, valid for 90 days, and use that to see what files and folders are there.

I can't tell what is relevant for your hacking game (under the assumption that you will not replicate particular executables, let alone GUI). At least you may want to be aware of `C:\Windows\System32\config\SAM` which will have the hashes of the passwords, and perhaps `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` that has the equivalent of `etc/hosts` from Linux.

Comment: This is great. I know you can find user installed Windows software in /Program files/ but where would you find them on linux?

Comment: Also i would like to replicate 'some' executables. Mostly for missions and such. But they will literally be text files filled with random "1/0" values that i simple change to .exe files. Just for show.

Comment: And lastly: It's a bit late to mention this(I'm sorry!) but when i said minimal, i meant like ten iconic folders to represent each OS. While all this is definantly useful, i already had the full file-trees. I just didn't know what folders were considered "iconic" to superusers. (Again, sorry!!)

Comment: @Cyanite you will find installed programs in `/usr/bin` (extended the answer to mention that, and also the "iconic" list). I suggest to mimic [file signatures](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) for example your `.exe` files may start with "MZ".

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been so helpful. I should beable to build a believeable filestructure thanks to you. I have no idea what to do with those file signatures though xD

Comment: @Cyanite you said you'd mimic files with random 0s and 1s, right? Well, the same thing, but make them start with the signature for the file type you try mimic. Why? because anybody with some experience on computer security that opens a `.exe` and don't see "MZ" at the start will go "that's a fake file!". You can try yourself, open an `.exe` with a text editor. Of course, just adding "MZ" won't make it a valid exe, but it may require a trained eye to tell.

Comment: Good call. However, I have opened .exe's before. All i ever see is a bunch of "(nul)"s. And if you've ever played "HackNet"(the inspiration for my game) it you cat his exe's you just see about two sentences worth of 1's and 0's.

Comment: Not that i'm trying to shun you or anything. I'm just stating my experience.

Comment: I suppose i could just compile a python program that only has one line of code, if i want to make things easer on me. I doubt anyone will notice that all the exe's have the same data in them. (from me not wanting to compile a custom exe for every single program) XD

Comment: I know this topic is pretty much closed, but i have one final question: Where are the activity logs for Windows? Google just turns up software that clears them for you.

Comment: @Cyanite Event Viewer

Comment: @Ramhound I mean what folder. Like linux is /var/

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277418.aspx

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/70328/where-how-does-windows-store-the-data-in-the-event-logs

Comment: Proper research is helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/359484/windows-7-move-location-of-eventlog